# Show Laravel Dusk tests from Homestead on Windows

Tags: php, windows, laravel, homestead, laravel-dusk

I'm playing with Laravel Dusk for the first time. I've running it on Homestead. It's running the example test, and give me the right feedback.

Now, I want to know if it's possible to see Dusk running in a browser. I run it on Vagrant Homestead, the VM is installed on my Windows 10 machine. Can I show the tests from homestead on my windows machine?

If it's not possible, but it is possible if I run Dusk from Windows it self. How can I start running it in windows. Do I need XAMPP for it? So install XAMPP make laravel up and running and run dusk from the Windows CMD?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Homestead there is no GUI and browser is running in headless mode so you cannot see it. However you can take screenshots and each time test fails, screenshot will be taken so you can see what's going wrong.

If you want to see browser while running test, you need to have it installed in your host system, in your case Windows. So yes - you need to install wamp (for example xampp), create Laravel application and then when running tests you should see Chrome while running tests.

Comment: Hi Marcin, thanks for you answer. I did install xampp and composer on my host (Windows) machine. And it's up and running. And it doesn't have any conflicts with the Homestead setup. So, for fast tests I can run it on Homestead (headless) and if I want a complete test and want to see it, I can run it on Windows.