# Laravel Dusk how to show the browser while executing tests

Tags: laravel, testing, laravel-5, laravel-dusk

I am writing some tests and I want to see whether Dusk correctly fills in the input fields but Dusk doesn't show the browser while running the tests, is there any way to force it to do that?

Comment: Are you running from inside Homestead or Outside? If inside there will be no display for it to be viewed on. If outside it should fire up chrome for each test.

Comment: Can you use screenshots for that?

Comment: @AndrewBibby I am not using Homestead/Vagrant

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I guess I can do that but it would be easier if the browser was visible

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Disable the headless mode in `tests\DuskTestCase.php` file `driver()` function:

```php
$options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
    //'--disable-gpu',
    //'--headless'
]);
```

Comment: maybe something changed, but the tests just hang forever when I comment these lines, no window opens

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: arch linux (--- padding to fill minimum comment length)

Comment: Are you using the latest ChromeDriver?

Comment: geez it's you.. you already asked me this in that github issue lol

*explains why this also doesn't work...

Answer (score 8):

#### Updated (2021):

You can disable headless with 2 methods:

**Method 1**: Add this to your `.env`

```
DUSK_HEADLESS_DISABLED=true
```

**Method 2**: Add this to your special test case if you don't need to show the browser for all tests

```php
protected function hasHeadlessDisabled(): bool
{
    return true;
}
```

Btw, I don't know why these are not mentioned in the documentation. I found the above methods myself from [DuskTestCase.php](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/blob/d806611fa472d668a95589ea84f0a7e8e1ca47a9/stubs/DuskTestCase.stub#L56-L60).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Answer for Laravel 8 & UP**

You can use `php artisan dusk --browse` to force showing the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Near the top of your `tests/DuskTestCase.php` file, add:

```
use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
```

In that same file, replace the entire `driver()` function with:

```
/**
 * Create the RemoteWebDriver instance.
 *
 * @return \Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver
 */
protected function driver() {
    $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments([
            //'--disable-gpu',
            //'--headless'//https://stackoverflow.com/q/49938673/470749
    ]);

    return RemoteWebDriver::create(
                    'http://localhost:9515', DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(
                            ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options
                    )
    );
}
```

Comment: See also https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/dusk-works-without-opening-browser#reply=379532 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/47960068/470749 and https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/is-there-any-way-to-show-browser-window-when-running-dusk-tests-from-within-homestead